# rqt_plot not publishing showing anything

Tags: ros, topic, rqt, ros-groovy, rqt-plot

[image: Rosanswers logo]

rqt_plot not publishing anything even thought there is data being published on the topic "mytopic". When I do `rostopic echo /mytopic` I get continious output with parameters changing given as follows(just posted a script out of the big output I am getting) :

```
  id: 3
    vs: 4

  - 
    id: 10
    vs: 1

  - 
    id: 13
    vs: 6

  - 
    id: 18
    vs: 1
 
  - 
    id: 19
    vs: 1
  
  - 
    id: 21
    vs: 8

  - 
    id: 27
    vs: 1

  - 
    id: 31
    vs: 1
```

However when I do rosrun rqt_plot rqt_plot /mytopic nothing is ouputted. Can somebody help me with this.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/68932/rqt_plot-not-publishing-showing-anything/) by [Gudjohnson](https://answers.ros.org/users/5370/gudjohnson/) on ROS Answers with karma: 100 on 2013-07-25

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) on 2013-08-07**:
What data types are the members of your topic? Are they numeric?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Try:

```
$ rqt_plot /%TOPIC_NAME%/%FIELD_NAME%
```

In your case:

```
$ rqt_plot /mytopic/id /mytopic/vs
```

Hope this works.

---

Originally posted by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) with karma: 10937 on 2013-07-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Gudjohnson](https://answers.ros.org/users/5370/gudjohnson/) on 2013-07-25**:
unfortunately this does not work. I do not understand why it does not work. For rosrun rqt_graph rqt_graph I get a graph in which I have one note which is publishing and subscribing to my /mytopic. rqt_plot should output the data being published on a topic but it does not show anything althought "rostopic echo /mytopic" shows that data is being published on mytopic.

**Comment by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) on 2013-08-07**:
I'm not sure either. Try `rosdep install rqt_plot` (this installs missing dependency if any) and tell us the result.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I know this is an old thread but I just want to post it here in case it would help anyone...

---

In order for rqt_plot to plot your topic, it should include a **timestamp**.
In other words, add a header to your customized message and write my_msg.header.stamp in it, then rqt_plot should work.

---

Originally posted by [Domi](https://answers.ros.org/users/125360/domi/) with karma: 21 on 2022-11-29

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2